# How to redirect role-based security exceptions to custom page (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, roles, roleprovider

I have very simple:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Administrator")]
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
```

This works - it denies access if role is not administrator. But when it denies access, I simply get a white page (all unhandled exceptions are picked up in Global file and emailed/logged). How do I tell it where to direct on failure? So I can show a security exception page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Global.asax.cs, add the following to Application_Error:

```
if (exception.GetType() == typeof(System.Security.SecurityException))
                Response.Redirect("SecurityExceptionPage.html");
```

Comment: This ok with server side proccesing! but what about 
webmethod with ajax call?  
they not raise application_error...